# What to do with big pieces of chocolate milk powder

Tags: food, kitchen, drinks

The chocolate powder I bought to add in milk came in plastic jar. Now accidentally one must have added a wet spoon to take the powder out. Now the fine powder has changed into sticky big stony masses, which are difficult to take out from the small mouth of the plastic jar. A lot of quantity is left and I don't want it to waste.
Right now what I do is put a spoon and try to break a big mass into small chunk so that it can come out from the mouth.
Or I try to hammer the mass so that powder can be formed, but that is very much time consuming and my hands ache after this.

Any idea/hack for this?

Answer (score 6):

At first, I was going to suggest breaking up the lumps in a more scientific way, by splitting them into smaller pieces with something like a chisel. But I have thought of a **hack**.

Pour warm water into the jar, not too full. Let it stand, stirring and prodding occasionally with a fork, until the lumps of chocolate have broken up and dissolved.

Next step is to freeze the liquid chocolate into portions, like you would make  ice or orange cubes, and keep them in the freezer. When you want a milky chocolate drink, defrost one or more cubes and stir into the milk. It might take one or two drinks to get the right amount of chocolate.

Comment: Btw, dumping a cube or two straight into hot milk should also work. (Or for cold drinks, thaw the cube directly in the cup/glass and then top it up with the milk.)